# Vote Early, Vote Often

Tags: discussion, votes

[From the TeX meta:](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often)

> Every Stack Exchange site will eventually end up with a different "base level" of voting --- that is, the expected number of upvotes for a question of a given level of excellence. (This effect occurs because people see a good question, but already with a certain number of votes, and think "oh, I would have upvoted this, but it already has enough".)

I'm not sure if it's what's happening lately, but it would seem there has been very little voting going on since the last few days. When you see a good question or answer, **vote it up!**

Otherwise, we won't end up with [enough high reputation users](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/):

> Does your site have a healthy middle class of users with vote up and down, and edit tag privileges? Does it have a healthy governing class of users with edit, close, and moderation privileges? All of this requires sufficient reputation, which in turn requires users to exercise their right to vote.
>
> ...
>
> Our sites are all intended to be a sort of representative democracy. While yearly moderator elections are an important part of that plan, voting on questions and answers is the primary mechanism through which the community governs the site on a day to day basis.

We only have [four users](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/badges/62/suffrage) with the Suffrage badge right now. We need more!

Comment: Isn't there also an overall rather low accept rate? Is that something inherent to the nature of the kind of questions we're asking? Or are the answers just generally not good enough? That's another question entirely, perhaps.

Comment: As for the suffrage tag, heck, I've cast some 500+ votes on SO, and I don't have that badge there yet. I could definitely vote more actively here - for now, I've mostly peeped in to see if there are any new interesting questions - but I don't see that we have "suffrage-level" activity here yet. Do we even have 30 posts in a day?

Comment: @DavidHedlund: We had over 50 questions on the first day, I believe.

Comment: Bah. Having said all that, I don't mean to come off as arguing against voting. I do see the point, especially now in the initial stages. I'll stress that I agree with your post in general, but I don't find the suffrage comment warranted :) I'll just shut up and go vote some...

Comment: @Borror0: Really? Oh, well, we have 7.4 questions a day, and 2.1 answers per question, according to the area 51 page. That should put us around 23 posts per day, but of course the first day can be expected to have extra high traffic (which would lower the *23* figure for the other days!)

Comment: @DavidHedlund: As of now, we have [331 posts total](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/327/will-the-comet-elenin-cause-significant-disruption-to-life-on-earth/331#331) if I understand their numbering system properly. That's 47 posts per day.

Comment: Looks like you're right! The Area51 figures seem oddly off, then. 104 questions in 7 days should be 15 rather than 7 per day... oh well. I believe we're digressing a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

Placeholder answer to get this question off the unanswered list